# Using Pyfhel to encrypt dataframe column

Tags: python, dataframe, encryption, pyspark

I am trying to use Pyfhel library to encrypt a pyspark dataframe column. But while performing the encryption function, i got the follwong error:

```
 An exception was thrown from the Python worker. Please see the stack trace below.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-151-e7ebc55523c7>", line 9, in <lambda>
  File "<ipython-input-151-e7ebc55523c7>", line 6, in en
  File "Pyfhel/Pyfhel.pyx", line 260, in Pyfhel.Pyfhel.Pyfhel.encryptFrac
  File "Pyfhel/Pyfhel.pyx", line 280, in Pyfhel.Pyfhel.Pyfhel.encryptFrac
RuntimeError: Missing a Public Key
```

There is the code that I use:

```
df1 = spark.createDataFrame([(1, 10, 1),(2, 13, 2), (3, 5, 3)], ["A", "B", "id"])
HE = Pyfhel()
HE.contextGen(p=65537, m=2**12)
HE.keyGen() # Generates both a public and a private key
def en(x):
 return HE.encryptFrac(x)
df1.show()
df1.printSchema()
udf_e = udf(lambda x: en(x) , FloatType())
df2 = df1.withColumn("A", udf_e(F.col("A")))
df2.show()
```

Comment: any help or response please

Comment: You should questions like this directly in the `Pyfhel` repository (Github issues)!